# Uninstall ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Hi can anyone please tell me how to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04? I have installed it via a live CD but now I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 and install ubuntu 10.04.  Can anyone please tell me the steps?

I want my windows to be there.  It should not go  .  Sorry I forgot to mention that mine is dual booting system

Answer (score 1):

You just install something else ( like 10.04 ) in its place.  Tell the installer to take over the whole disk and 12.04 will be gone.

Comment: But i want my windows to be there.It should not go.sorry i forgot to mention that mine is dual booting system

Comment: @Nikki, then in that case, tell the installer to replace the existing Ubuntu installation.

Comment: will i get that option while installing ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: @Nikki, you should.  If not, then choose manual and point it to the same partitions the previous install used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to uninstall if you just want to reinstall with something else.

If the machine has more than just the Ubuntu install on it - you'd want to pick the Something else.

Then you will get a window with the existing partitions.

Choose the linux one - change partition - then pick / as the mountpoint.

Save that and it will go back to the partition window - you carry on from there.

If you have a seperate home - do the same for /home as /.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a very descriptive answer about removing Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu/143482#143482).

After that, install Ubuntu 10.04 the same way you installed Ubuntu 12.04.

Hope this helps.